# Enable static import wildcards for some classes in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to enable static import wildcards for classes usually used in tests, e.g. **org.hamcrest.Matchers**.
So, when I'll execute the [*Optimize Imports*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/optimizing-imports.html) action instead of this :

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.any;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
```

I would get this :

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Is it possible to do that in IDEA ?

**Solution**

Settings :: Editor :: Code Style :: Java => Imports.
[image]

Comment: On IntelliJ 15 there is "Packages to Use Import with '*'" in the screen that you mention. Did you miss that?

Comment: Yes - there's a "Static" checkbox on the left side of the entries in the table.

Comment: Thank you, it works, one can write package as well as class names there.